# Android run single espresso test from command line

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, android-debug

Is there a way to run a single test inside a UI test class in Android from the command line

```
//I can run all the tests with this command 

 $ adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.me.app.tests.Food.EatingTests com.me.app.dev.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

// this is my test class
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EatingTests {

@Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {}
}

@Test
@Priority1
public void eatApple() throws Exception {}

@Test
@Priority1
public void eatBanana() throws Exception {}
}
```

Is there a way to only run eatApple() instead of running the whole class with all the tests (eatApple and eatBanana)

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is the test method name that gets appended with the class name followed by a "#"
Example: `adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.me.app.tests.Food.EatingTests#test_method_name com.me.app.dev.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`